# Unexpected throttling in kafka consumers

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Kafka cluster with zookeeper running. I'm running into an unexpected throttling scenario in Kafka. I see a ton of the below log entries.

> [2021-02-18 20:56:57,541] DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-kafka-connect-splunk-hec-sink-all_remaining_topics-1, groupId=kafka-connect-splunk-hec-sink-all_remaining_topics] Node 0 sent an incremental fetch response with throttleTimeMs = 1003 for session 1007820287 with 0 response partition(s), 2 implied partition(s) (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler)

I don't have quotas enabled so I'd expect the default quotas to apply, which are very high/unlimited. Any ideas why Kafka would throttle a consumer without quotas enabled?

I'd also be curious where I can see the reason for it being throttled (e.g. is is bandwidth, I/O etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a bug in Kafka https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/8959/files